# Navigating from view to view in mvc2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Is it possible to navigate directly from a view to another view without having to go down to the controller level?

Comment: By the way, please work on accepting some answers on your previous questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "navigate" you mean to render one view in another, you can use `Html.RenderPartial`. If you mean creating a link with a URL that will invoke some other view directly when it is clicked, no: it would break the "C" part of MVC.

Comment: Thats what I figured.  Might as well just call the controller and navigate to the view from there.  Thanks.